# can not load 3d model in libgdx

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx, assets

I've made some 3d models for my small project. But when I load them using assets manager, logcat gives me an error.

There is the code:

```
public InGameScreen(TinyBattles game) { // screen constructor 

    ...

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("3d/tankbody6.obj", Model.class);
    loading = true;

}

private void doneLoading() {
    Model tank = assets.get("3d/tankbody6.obj", Model.class);

    ModelInstance tankInstanse = new ModelInstance(tank);
    tankInstanse.transform.setToTranslation(0, 0, 0);

    tankA.instance = tankInstanse;
    loading = false;
}
```

Error:

```
03-08 18:12:05.799  12397-12412/com.tinybattles003.game.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 22871
Process: com.tinybattles003.game.android, PID: 12397
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: 3d/tankbody6.obj
        at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:123)
        at com.tinybattles003.game.screens.InGameScreen.doneLoading(InGameScreen.java:92)
        at com.tinybattles003.game.screens.InGameScreen.render(InGameScreen.java:108)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
        at com.tinybattles003.game.general.TinyBattles.render(TinyBattles.java:22)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

It is not only about this exact model, I tried to load each of them this the same result. But the weirdest thing is that I can load model in any project, but this.

Comment: Need more code, where is the loading variable being evaluated? Are you calling the assets manager update method?

Comment: Never ever use .obj files.

Comment: I also tried .g3db but it is all the same

Comment: You are never calling the doneLoading() method, nor are you calling assets.update(). So it is very unlikely that this snippet includes enough information to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: I have doneloading() in render() method

Comment: I did forgot the assets.update() . Now it works fine. Thanks, @Xoppa

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your model is loaded from asset folder by invoking the finishLoading() method. It pauses render method until the model is completely loaded.

```
assets = new AssetManager();
assets.load("3d/tankbody6.obj", Model.class);
loading = true;
assets.finishLoading()
```